# Do there exist "quasi-periodic" minimal surfaces?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I know there is a famous class of minimal surface, the triply periodic minimal surface such as P-surface, D-surface, etc. You can find many examples in this website: http://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/examples/periodic/periodic.html#gw.

My question is whether there exists a ''quasi-periodic minimal surface'', the minimal surface that can fill the 3-dimensional space, but has no translational symmetries, or not. If so, please give me examples.

I'll appleciate your help!

Comment: What does it mean "can fill"?

Comment: Sorry, I can't give the word robust definition, but "can fill" means "can tessellate" casually.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a paper that seems to answer your question:

https://tinyurl.com/47euba8n

"Theorem 1.2. There exist complete, properly embedded minimal surfaces in Euclidean space which are quasi-periodic and non-periodic. These surfaces have infinite genus, infinitely many planar ends and two limit ends."

Comment: It would be nice to have a picture. Pity they don't have any. Then maybe a description: _"Heuristically, our surfaces are constructed by taking an infinite stack of horizontal planes $(P_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$, ordered by their height, and gluing $n_k$ catenoidal necks between the planes $P_k$ and $P_{k+1}$ for each $k\in\mathbb Z$. It is clear that in this way, we obtain a surface of type $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$."_